# QSqlTableModel list of transactions

Tags: qsqlquery, qsqltablemodel, pyqt6

I am writing a PyQt6 QSqlTableModel application. I'm using manual update and submitAll(). I want to capture the sql statements which were successfully executed. The executedQuery() method reports only the last query, but several may have been executed by submitAll(). There doesn't seem to be a way to step through the executed queries one at a time.

I can use brute force by tailing the database system log files, but I'd rather use a PyQt6 method.

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: AFAIK, I doubt it's possible. By looking at the [sources](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/sql/models/qsqltablemodel.cpp.html#_ZN21QSqlTableModelPrivate4execERK7QStringbRK10QSqlRecordS5_), QSqlTableModel uses a *private* QSqlQuery to update the database.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you; I suspected as much. One would think they would provide a method. There doesn't seem to be a PyQt6 (or 5) bug tracker. The Qt bug tracker "project" dropdown list doesn't have Py among its choices. Do you know of a PyQt6 bug tracker?

Comment: PyQt is not the official python binding, and has no affiliation with Qt. PySide is the official binding, but in any case this is not related to Python, it's a Qt API issue. You could file a feature request, but I'd suggest you to wait some time as some more experienced users might give you a more accurate reply (or even a solution). Consider that PyQt has a mailing list (being it a binding, there's little point in a bug tracker), so you could also write there and maybe the PyQt maintainer might give you a more definite answer on this: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt

Comment: @musicamante Thank you again for taking time to address this issue. Now I know why there are so many PySide examples on the Qt web site, and no PyQt examples. Since PyQt6 is brand new (and the documentation, by their own admission, a disaster), I will take your advice and wait for things to mature. There are several features that don't work, but without a bug tracker it's futile to bug the maintainers. Pun intended.

Comment: In general, you should prefer the official Qt documentation anyway (not even the PySide docs), there's little point in looking for the python docs, as it would practically be the same: 99.9% of the times, the function arguments and returned value types are the same (a `void` function means a function that returns `None` in Python), with few exceptions that can be easily verified in the python interactive shell with `help(class.function)`; as said, they are *bindings*, if a feature doesn't work, the issue is most probably with Qt, not PyQt/PySide, *but* there are occasions in which there is ->

Comment: -> a bug in the binding. For that, you can write to the PyQt ml (it's one of its purposes, the maintainer won't be *bugged* for that) or file a report on the Qt bug tracker with the PYSIDE tag. But, for this specific issue (and unless I'm mistaken and there actually is a possible solution), this has absolutely nothing to do with Python (no PyQt, no PySide), as the feature is missing in the Qt API itself. Considering the scope, I sincerely doubt that it will be added unless specifically requested. Instead of waiting for that, just write to the mailing list (or Qt forums), and you will know it.